# Can you make an alpha character push do something using C?

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I am new at programming and was wondering if you could give me some advice as to how to make a alphanumeric character press do something using C? I would like to program a different function for each character pressed. Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's a very broad question. What can you do? Can you input a character, and filter invalid inputs? Do you know `main` and `switch`?

Comment: Standard C has no mechanism for responding to individual keypresses. If that's what you want, you either need to look at OS specific APIs, or use a library like [ncurses](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ncurses/info).

Comment: I want to make a gui using windows.h and I was wondering if you could use alpha character press movie a picture on the gui?

Comment: You can intercept the `WM_CHAR` message.

Answer (score 2):

In your [window procedure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/about-window-procedures), you can react to [WM_KEYDOWN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) messages. Your window will receive such a message when the user starts pressing down a key. When the user lets go of the key, you will receive a [WM_KEYUP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keyup) message.

See [this tutorial on window messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/window-messages) for the basics on how to handle window messages.